# HAProxy config with log-format. Need replace string in the log

Tags: regex, haproxy

I have a working config of HAProxy that captured the Authorization header in log file.
Captured authorization string looks like `Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0Cg==`.

I need to remove `Basic`  and convert `dGVzdDp0ZXN0Cg==` from base64 to original text.
I could convert whole captured string into base64 like
`%[capture.req.hdr(0),base64]` but how convert it back to original?

Part of config file:

```
tcp-request content capture req.hdr(Authorization) len 128
log-format "%Tl "Client"-"%ci" "ConnectsTo"-"%fi:%fp" AuthorizationHeader:%[capture.req.hdr(0),regsub(Basic\s*,)] %hs"
```

Comment: So your authorization string will always have `basic` or it can have other words as well?

Comment: Always have "Basic " at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove "Basic " from line beginning and decode AuthorizationHeader from base64 to original just need add %[capture.req.hdr(0),regsub(Basic\s*,),b64dec]
Full config:

```
tcp-request content capture req.hdr(Authorization) len 128
log-format "Client-%ci Server-%fi:%fp AuthorizationHeader:%[capture.req.hdr(0),regsub(Basic\s*,),b64dec]"
```